# Python: Access variable in Database

Tags: python, database, variables

I am trying to automate making multiple entries into a .db database using python. Here is the code I started of with.

```
`import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')


conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAMEY) \
      VALUES (number, 'Paul')");

runsloop1 = 100
while runsloop1 != 0:
    runsloop1 = runsloop1 - 1



cursor = conn.execute("SELECT id, name from COMPANY")
for row in cursor:
   print ("ID = ", row[0])
   print ("NAME = ", row[1])

conn.close()`
```

I tried to put the conn.execute into the runloops1 loop and access the variable like this:
`while runsloop1 != 0: runsloop1 = runsloop1 - 1 conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAMEY) \ VALUES (runsloop1, 'Paul')");`

but I got this Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 13, in <module> conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAMEY) \ sqlite3.OperationalError: table COMPANY has no column named NAMEY` 
NAMEY is the name of the variable I tried with.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says `table COMPANY has no column named NAMEY` can you re-check your table if it is having NAMEY column?

Comment: NAMEY is the name of the variable.

Comment: But here ```conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAMEY) \
      VALUES (number, 'Paul')");``` NAMEY is not a variable. it just string. try to change it to NAME and execute. if you are trying  to accomplish something else let us know.